# cmake compile_commands.json for interface target

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I have a simple c++ library that should be shipped as header-only library. The library depends on other libraries installed through [CPM](https://github.com/cpm-cmake/CPM.cmake).

I'm using VS code and the `compile_commands.json` in order to notify VS code about the include paths from CPM packages. That does work as long as the project is configured as shared/static library or binary.
When using an `INTERFACE` target it however doesn't work anymore (compile_commands.json is generated but VS code shows include paths errors).

How do I use `compile_commands.json` with an interface target (header-only library) ?

*The configuration below does work when defining binary target ( replacing `INTERFACE` with `PUBLIC`)!*

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21 FATAL_ERROR)

project(CpmCompileCommandsBug
    LANGUAGES CXX
)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

include(cmake/CPM.cmake)

CPMAddPackage(
    NAME yaml-cpp
    VERSION 0.6.3
    GITHUB_REPOSITORY jbeder/yaml-cpp
    GIT_TAG yaml-cpp-0.6.3
    OPTIONS
        "YAML_CPP_INSTALL ON"
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE yaml-cpp)

# the below target config does work
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC main.cpp)
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC yaml-cpp)
```

**main.cpp**:

```cpp
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
```

Comment: "When using a static library (INTERFACE target) ..." - No, INTERFACE target doesn't mean a static library. A static library is created using STATIC keyword.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for correcting me, I was actually talking about a header-only library - not a static one. I updated the question.

Comment: A **header-only** library has **no source files**, only headers. Why do you add `main.cpp` to it?

Comment: Have you tried adding the list of headers as sources to `add_library(CpmCompileCommandsBug INTERFACE include/header1.hpp ...)`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes I was stuck on that contradiction for way too long, thanks to your notice I realized I don't want a header-only target (which doesn't include any sources) but an object library instead. I honestly didn't know about object libraries.

Comment: @AlexReinking thanks for the hint but as suggested above, the interface target doesn't take any source file inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was simply using the wrong target. Interfaces don't include any source files and thus won't generate any meaningful `compile_commands.json`.

What I was looking for is the **object target** which solves my issue completely.

Just for the reference, this is how the "correct" CMakeLists.txt would look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21 FATAL_ERROR)

project(CpmCompileCommandsBug
    LANGUAGES CXX
)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

include(cmake/CPM.cmake)

CPMAddPackage(
    NAME yaml-cpp
    VERSION 0.6.3
    GITHUB_REPOSITORY jbeder/yaml-cpp
    GIT_TAG yaml-cpp-0.6.3
    OPTIONS
        "YAML_CPP_INSTALL OFF"
)

# using OBJECT instead of INTERFACE allows passing source files
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} OBJECT main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC yaml-cpp)
```